# How to solve logical problem in Leetcode 2sum/3sum questions

Tags: java, logical-or

I have a problem for twosum, it is 
Given an int array num and an int target, find how many unique pairs in the array such that their sum is equal to target. Return the number of pairs.

My code sometimes get the Wrong Answer during the test case
like nums = [1,2,3,4], target = 5
my code will only return 1 pair.

Here is my code

```
public int twoSum6(int[] nums, int target) {
    int pair = 0;
    ...
   Arrays.sort(nums);

   int left = 0;
   int right = nums.length - 1;

  while(left < right){
      if(nums[left] + nums[right] == target  ){
        pair++;
        left++;
        right--;
        while(left < right &&  nums[left] == nums[left + 1]  ){
          left++;
      }
       while(left < right &&  nums[right] == nums[right - 1]){
          right--;
      }
      }


      if(nums[left] + nums[right] < target){
          left++;
      }else{
          right--;
      }
  } return pair;
```

}

Here is the sample test
Input: nums = [1, 1, 2, 45, 46, 46], target = 47
Output: 2
Explanation:
1 + 46 = 47
2 + 45 = 47

so if the testcase is [1,2,3,4] and the target is 5, the actual output for that is 2
my output is 1, I think I have something wrong for my logical, but I am not sure where is that

Comment: what is the specification of inputs? you are only searching for 2 pairs?

Comment: it is: “Given an array of integers, find how many unique pairs in the array such that their sum is equal to a specific target number. Please return the number of pairs.”